# How to interpret Granger Test?

Tags: r, time-series, granger-causality

I hope to check the relationship between the two lines. Both of them have annual data with 12 data points (see an example for two months' data.

| Year | Comsumer_Sentiment_Index | Compound Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Feb-20 | 101.0 | 0.20 |
| Mar-20 | 89.1 | 0.12 |

I first check the stationarity for the two lines and they are both stationary with ADF tests

```
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
data:  myts
Dickey-Fuller = -2.8307, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.2559
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

```
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
data:  myts_1
Dickey-Fuller = -2.8186, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.2605
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Then I did a Granger test but I found no significance for both directions

```
Granger causality test

Model 1: Consumer_Sentiment_Index ~ Lags(Consumer_Sentiment_Index, 1:3) + Lags(Predicted_Compunt_Tweet_Sentiment, 1:3)
Model 2: Consumer_Sentiment_Index ~ Lags(Consumer_Sentiment_Index, 1:3)
  Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
1      2                 
2      5 -3 3.1047 0.2531

Granger causality test
Model 1: Predicted_Compunt_Tweet_Sentiment ~ Lags(Predicted_Compunt_Tweet_Sentiment, 1:3) + Lags(Consumer_Sentiment_Index, 1:3)
Model 2: Predicted_Compunt_Tweet_Sentiment ~ Lags(Predicted_Compunt_Tweet_Sentiment, 1:3)
  Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
1      2                 
2      5 -3 0.3509 0.7975
```

Does it mean that these two lines do not have any relationship? I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests show that values at time points t-1, t-2, t-3 in one of the time series do not have any predictive power for the value of the other time series at time t.

This does not imply that the two time series do not have any relationship. You could, for example, find that the contemporaneous correlation between your two time series is nonzero, i.e. `cor(Predicted_Compunt_Tweet_Sentiment, Consumer_Sentiment_Index) != 0`.

You might be thinking about cointegration. There exists a result stating that (perhaps someone else can give a reference in comments?)

1. if two time series x, and y, have a unit root, and
2. if they are cointegrated,
3. then there exists granger causality from x to y, y to x, or both ways.

According to your ADF tests, 1. is not true, so 2. cannot hold (only unit root time series can be cointegrated), so 3. is not implied either.